# Why NSLayoutConstraint is optional type?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

Usually I avoid to ask a new question here on stackoverflow, because 90% of questions easily solved by searching. But sometimes you can't do in this way.

I have several objects `class GameTimer : UIView` that I add to the array
`var timersArray: [GameTimer?] { get set }` of my view controller dynamically. 
I've implemented some small class to handle constraints for that objects. Every time I add a new object, I also add constraints for portrait and landscape mode.

```
class ConstraintsContainer {

    var portraitConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    var landscapeConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

func setGeneralConstraints(timerView: GameTimer?, timerViewSize: CGFloat) {
    timerView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    timerView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: timerViewSize).isActive = true
    timerView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: timerViewSize).isActive = true
    print("General constraints")
}

func getDeviceOrientation() {

        if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portrait || UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(portraitConstraints)
        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(landscapeConstraints)
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use this class in my view controller

```
var constraintsContainer = ConstraintsContainer()
```

and set some values to the instance

```
constraintsContainer.portraitConstraints = [
            timersArray[0]?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:    view.topAnchor, constant: view.frame.height/4.5),
            (timersArray[0]?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor))
        ]

        constraintsContainer.landscapeConstraints = [
            (timersArray[0]?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: view.frame.height/6.5)),
            (timersArray[0]?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor))
        ]
```

I have an error warning from XCode telling me that *"value of optional type 'NSLayoutConstraint?' is not unwrapped"* and suggests me to unwrap every constraint like this `(timersArray[0]?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: view.frame.height/4.5))!`

So, can't get a clue why `NSLayoutConstraint` type appears optional here, considering it's reference `class NSLayoutConstraint : NSObject`.
Is it possible to avoid it to be an optional? The reason - when I deactivate constraints for particular object, then clear constraints from `constraintsContainer` and remove object of my `GameTimer` class type from `timersArray` and have implemented this unwrapping I caught an error -

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

```
 func deactivate() {

    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(constraintsContainer.portraitConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(constraintsContainer.landscapeConstraints)
    constraintsContainer.portraitConstraints.removeAll()
    constraintsContainer.landscapeConstraints.removeAll()
}
```

Why NSLayoutConstraint appears to be optional in my particular case?

Comment: `timersArray` is an optional, so what you have is "optional chaining".

Comment: Why `NSConstraint` appears here to be an optional type that demands unwrapping and causes an error when the element of an array turns to be nil. I declared constrains to be `var portraitConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]` not `[NSLayoutConstraint?]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the process of querying, calling properties, subscripts and methods on an optional that may be 'nil' is defined as optional chaining. Optional chaining return two values −

```
if the optional contains a 'value' then calling its related property, methods and subscripts returns values.

if the optional contains a 'nil' value all its its related property, methods and subscripts returns nil.
```

Since multiple queries to methods, properties and subscripts are grouped together failure to one chain will affect the entire chain and results in 'nil' value.

and your  timersArray  is Optional ?

Comment: Thank you for answering on a part of my question! Yes, when I remove  `GameTimer?` element from an array it turns to be nil, but why `NSLayoutConstraint` appears to be optional here and XCode demand from me force unwrapping? I do not declare it as an optional type "?" `var portraitConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]`

Comment: Got it. That was not obvious for me - when I call non-optional instance that inside uses property of optional instance - the resulting call is optional and that's why XCode wants unwrapping of it.